# Finding largest empty circular area in 2D space

Tags: geometry, 2d, computational-geometry

Given a 2D space inhabited by circle shapes (grey), is there an easy way to find the largest empty circular area (blue)? I guess I have to look at space partioning, maybe quadtrees, but I'm curious as to whether there might be existing solutions, especially for circular shapes?

[image: 2D circles]

My idea (neither thought through or implemented, and computationally expensive):

1. Divide the space into a grid, the finer, the more precise
2. At every grid point, calculate D, the smallest distance to any of the neighbouring circles C_i (= distance to center of C_i - radius of C_i)
3. Choose the grid point that maximizes D

Comment: If grey spheres has equal radii, consider using `Voronoi diagram`

Comment: This is solved by the Voronoi diagram of the given circles (whatever their radii). The center is one of the vertices of the diagram. https://www2.imm.dtu.dk/pubdb/edoc/imm5297.pdf

Comment: JTS' `LargestEmptyCircle` does exactly what you're looking for

Comment: @micycle very cool, thanks! It seems they even use the same implementation idea. It won't find a circular area outside of the convex hull though, which is fine by me.

Answer (score 0):

I solved a similar problem by making a binary image and then translating the coordinates to produce a triangulation using "Delaunay" which is the same principle of Voronoi tessellation, but instead of separate polygons, triangulate equidistance from each point (pixel).
The code then computes the circumcenters of all vertices and finally computes the largest:

```
# Convert 255 to 1
z[z == 255] = 1

# Now, 'z' represents the binary image with values 0 and 1
binary_image = z

# Extract coordinates of points (where binary_image == 1)
points_y, points_x = np.where(binary_image == 1)
points = np.column_stack((points_x, points_y))

# Compute Delaunay triangulation
tri = Delaunay(points)

# Compute Voronoi diagram
vor = Voronoi(points)

# Calculate circumcenter distances and radii
circumcenter_distances = []
radii_data = {'Circumcenter': [], 'Radius': []}

for i, simplex in enumerate(tri.simplices):
    circumcenter = np.mean(tri.points[simplex], axis=0)

    # Calculate distances from the circumcenter to all vertices
    vertex_distances = [distance.euclidean(circumcenter, vertex) for vertex in tri.points[simplex]]

    circumcenter_distances.append(vertex_distances)

    # Find the minimum distance to any vertex as the radius
    min_distance = min(vertex_distances)
    radii_data['Circumcenter'].append(circumcenter)
    radii_data['Radius'].append(min_distance)

# Convert the data to a pandas DataFrame
radii_df = pd.DataFrame(radii_data)

# Find the largest empty circle
largest_empty_circle = radii_df.loc[radii_df['Radius'].idxmax()]
```

The code works well with asymmetric shapes, so I assume that it will work with circles